# How to use require function with ob_*?

Tags: php, html, include, require, ob-start

I have 3 files called **Casino-review.php, functions.php, newfile.html**. My problem is when i am creating a html file called **newfile.html** from **functions.php** and copying php output data from **casino-review.php** in the **newfile.html**. It's working properly good but, when the **functions.php** creating html file and copying data in it, It's not showing **header.php and footer.php** i don't know why. I think you know what i am saying.

I mean when **newfile.html** is created it's not showing **header and footer** this is not an error this an problem that i don't know how to fix i have tried googling so many times but didn't find any solutions. I hope you understand me.

**Note:** This is not error everything is fine.

The first one is **Casino-review.php** and it's code is.

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
?>

<h1><?php echo "Hello world"; ?></h1>

<?php
require 'footer.php'
?>
```

The second file **functions.php** and it's code is.

```
$fileName = "wow.html";
$to = "casinos/all/".$fileName;
$from = "casinos/casino-review.php";
if ($createFile = fopen($to, "w")) {
   ob_start();
   require_once("$from"); // Getting php output from Casino-review.php
   file_put_contents($to, ob_get_contents());
   ob_end_clean();
   fclose($createFile);
   echo "Wait for 5 seconds";
}
```

The third file is **newfile.html** and it's code is.

```
// Header is not including
<h1>Hello world</h1>
// Footer is not including
```